# How to include a string chain in a LaTeXed subscript in Python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, format, latex, subscript

I want to write in the legend of a matplotlib figure a variable with a subscript using LaTeX. One possible code for this kind of problem could be:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a, b = 1, 0
string = "({0},{1})".format(n,l)
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1e3)

fig = plt.figure(0)
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x), 'b', label = r"Function for $E_{}$".format(string))
ax.legend()
plt.savefig("example_fig.png")
```

However, this code produces a plot where only the first element of the string chain "string" is used:
[Example of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3wpE.png)

I tried to solve this problem using `.format{string[:]}` or `$E_{{}}$` but it doesn't seem to work, and I don't have more ideas.

Comment: `"{{({0},{1})}}".format`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use three braces, a brace is escaped with another brace so two `{{` print a literal `{`. The third gets formatted.

```
>>> string = '(1,2)'
>>> 'E_{{{}}}'.format(string)
'E_{(1,2)}'
```

[Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) for reference.